# c macro, check parameter and replace by nop

Tags: c

I have defined some multilevel macros for GPIO toggle (and set analog, digital, etc) for my MCU. Using gcc. Like this

```
#define LED  B,2

gpio_make_amalog(LED) 
gpio_high(LED)
gpio_low(LED)
```

and so on.

The problem is when I try to reuse code (like a recent project) I may not use that gpio, so in every module I have to go and comment out is LED is not defined

```
//gpio_low(LED)
```

The question is, there is a possibility to test a macro parameter inside that macro, so if LED is not defined, a Nop() to be inserted.

Thank you in advance,

PS.

`#ifdef` is not quite practical. My recent example was a 4x4 column keyboard matrix code and these days I wanted to use a 3x4 keyboard phone type)

So I had a lot of if(gpio(COL1_ROW_4)) {} that needs to be commented.

If the gpio() macro was smarter, a nop will keep the code harmless or so.

Comment: "*wuite*" err, what please?

Comment: Please post the definition of at least one of those `gpio_`\* macros. And please explain a bit better what changes when you from from 4x4 to 3x4. Currently, I can't understand how an `#ifdef`, practical or not, isn't your only alternative to rewriting everything.

Comment: I guess he doesn't want to skipp all gpio* calls but only those for pins that are not used. Like the missing ROW_4 with his changed matrix.

Comment: Why is #ifdef not practical? It strongly depends where you put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is, there is a possibility to test a macro parameter inside that macro, so if LED is not defined, a Nop() to be inserted.

There are all sorts of fun games you can play with macro expansion, but there are no *bona fide* conditionals.  All your strictly macro-based alternatives revolve around macros expanding differently under different circumstances.  It might be possible to use such tricks to achieve your objective, but even evaluating how feasible that is would require knowing a lot more about the values your macros can be defined to take.

You should consider different approaches.  For example, you reject making your macro *definitions* conditional on the definedness of `LED`, etc., but I see no barrier to making your macro *uses* conditional on the definedness of the macros used in their invocations.  That is, instead of your current practice of commenting out macro invocations you don't want, just wrap each of those in appropriate conditional compilation directives once and for all:

```
#ifdef LED
gpio_make_amalog(LED);
#endif

#ifdef COL1_ROW_4
if (gpio(COL1_ROW_4)) {
    // ...
} 
#endif
```

... or even ...

```
if (
#ifdef COL2_ROW_2
    gpio(COL2_ROW_2)
#else
    0
#endif
) {
    // ...
}
```

That will be approximately as much work as commenting out all those invocations once.

Alternatively, if your uses involve manipulation of the whole set of applicable pins, then you might find an [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) approach useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in any .h file that you are sure that will be included where LED are used...

```
#ifndef LED
#define GPIO_MAKE_ANALOG Nop()
#define GPIO_HIGH(A, B) Nop()
#define GPIO_LOW(A, B) Nop()
#endif

#ifdef LED
#define GPIO_MAKE_ANALOG gpio_make_analog(A, B)
#define GPIO_HIGH(A, B) gpio_high(A, B)
#define GPIO_LOW(A, B) gpio_low(A, B)
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you both for comments, but #ifdef is not practical, see edit post

Comment: Let me see if I got this straight... you want that gpio_high and gpio_low or a macro that wrap those functions know wheter led is defined or not, and if not send a Nop()?  See edit answer

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your macro calls with a `USE_GPIO` define.

```
#ifdef USE_GPIO
#  define LED  B,2
#endif

#ifdef USE_GPIO
#  gpio_make_amalog(LED) 
#  gpio_high(LED)
#  gpio_low(LED)
#endif
```

Then you define this macro in your main file, **before** you include your header file. This is a feature test macro.

Notice, however, that if you are doing modular compilation and this code is in a `.c` file, you will need to specify  the flag in the command line with the `-D` option (assuming GCC).

Comment: typo: you spelled `USE_GPIO` differently in the two instances.